# How to increase/decrease rectangle size according to size of label when i touch on label in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uilabel

i have one rectangle and two labels like label1, label2 in a subview class.

1. label1 is fixed inside the rectangle or you can say rectangle has label1 inside it.
2. label2 is some time away from label1 on the screen, and it is draggable as i applied touches moved method in my subview and make `label2.userInteractionEnabled = YES`
3. Now i want to connect label2 with label1 with touch and it is working fine but the rectangle size is not updating .
4. When i connect label2 with label1 then the rectangle size should also be update as label1+label2 size to fit both labels in it.How can i got this stuff ...
   Here is my code.

   ```
   _targetRect = [[UIView alloc]init];
   self.frame = CGRectMake(10,70,70,30
   [self addsubView:_targetRect];
   ```

   For Label one same x, y positions as targetRect

   ```
    label1 = [[UILabel alloc]init];
   self.frame = CGRectMake(10,70, width, hight)];
   [self addsubView: label1];
   ```

   For label2 x, y positions are away from label one as here

   ```
    label2 = [[UILabel2 alloc]init];
   self.frame = CGRectMake(100,70, width, hight)];
   label2.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
   [self addsubView:label2];
   ```

Comment: where are you updating Rectangle frame after adding two lable. You must add two labels size and assign it to Rectangle.

Comment: – Gagan_iOS 2 this is the issue how can i grab it inside touches begin method?

Comment: You already have size of labels, so detect when both label touches each other & set size of your view to sum of these two.  In your touch method just  sum size of labels & assign to view's size.

Comment: why you are not making the label subview of _targetRect?

Comment: @sipa i have a idea when you drag a label onto another label you can get the text of the label2 so the you can concate the string of label1 and label2 and make it the text of label1 and update the label width according to size it require for the string and then update the frame accordingly like the label1

Comment: – Ahmed Sahib i not want to concate  the string of two labels as the label1 color and label2 color are different and there should be a margin of difference .....

Comment: Try to use setFrame in touchesBegan method.

Comment: Show your touch handling code.

Comment: – Duncan C see here - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.gameLayer];
    
    if (touch.view != self.gameLayer)
        [touch view].center = currentPoint;
    
}
gameLayer is my subView

Comment: @sipa ok then when you drag your label2 on label 1 calculate the total width it required to fit in the rect then label2 will start from label1.x+label1.width now the rect size with be label2.x+label2.width

Answer (score 1):

Redesign the rectangle frame size after the label2 frame design. like,

```
_targetRect.frame = CGRectMake(10,70, width, label1.frame,size.height+label2.frame,size.height)];
```